# I used two while loops in C language. i need help TT

Tags: c

1. 

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 2, j = 1;
    
    while (i < 10) {
        
        while (j < 10) {
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", i, j, i * j);
            j++;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

2. 

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 2, j = 0;
    
    while (i < 10) {
        j = 1;
        while (j < 10) {
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", i, j, i * j);
            j++;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I tried to make multiplication tables with two while loops.
First code doesn't work. it showed only 2*1=2 ~ 2*9=18.
But second code works well.....
Sorry for my bad English TT.
Just i want to know what is wrong and what is different in 2 codes.

Comment: The second one works because you reset `j` to a value that will allow the inner loop to execute. In the first once `j` is larger than 9 it stays that way forever. Unless you have a good reason to use `while` loops I would suggest `for` loops instead and minimizing the scope of variables as much as possible. If you declared `j` inside the outer loop you couldn't have this issue since it would be created and initialized every time.

Comment: You don't reset your inner loop variable `j` after the inner loop is done, so the inner loop will not execute again.

Answer (score 1):

In the second one you reset `j`. In the first on you don't reset `j` so you only get into the 2nd loop once.

Answer (score 1):

In first code, variable j is not reset to 1 in first loop

while (i < 10) { }

That results in the second loop

while (j < 10) {

to only runs once when i = 2 and never runs again, because the value of j has reached 10 and never changed again until i reached 10.

Answer (score 1):

You reset j to 1 in the second code that helped you in getting all the tables otherwise the value of j once exceeds 9 it stops after printing only table of 2

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are correct: the error in the first code sample is not resetting the value in `j` after the first outer loop operation.

However, they could be improved by replacing your `while` loops with equivalent `for` loops with *locally scoped* `i` and `j` variables which handles the reset.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", i, j, i * j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```